# Convert LocalDate ObservableList to String Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, observablelist

I want to transfer some dates as strings from an ObservableList to an ArrayList in java (JavaFX).

I have tried to use a for loop to add the data but it didn't work. Can you please help me with that. Thanks

This is my ObservableList

```
ObservableList<LocalDate> selectedDates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

This is my ArrayList

```
static ArrayList<String> FinalDateArrayList;
```

I am filling the selectedDates ObservableList from the DatePicker so it works fine

```
 startDatePicker.setOnAction(event -> selectedDates.add(startDatePicker.getValue()));
```

This is the for loop of transferring dates as string to my ArrayList

```
 for(int i =0 ; i < selectedDates.size(); i++)
     {
         FinalDateArrayList.add(selectedDates.get(i).toString());   
     }
```

It didnt show me the error.

Comment: your `selectedDates` is empty

Comment: No, it has data in it beacuse I am using a for loop inside a method that already fill the Observablelist by data.

Comment: There is data in it, I just want a way of transfering the data to the arraylist @Oswald

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: have you initialized `FinalDateArrayList`? otherwise it works for me

Comment: Thank you for your relpy. Not really, How can I initialize it, Do you mean like this?  `static  ArrayList<String> FinalDateArrayList = null;` or How?

Comment: @Oswald I have tried to set it as " " as well

Comment: No you'll get a `NullPointerException` if you initialize it with `null`, do this `ArrayList<String> FinalDateArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I just did it, thank you very much mate, If you just post your comment as an answer so I can vote up. Thanks boss @Oswald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your `FinalDateArrayList` with a non-null value

`ArrayList<String> FinalDateArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Also, though not related to the question, use `static` only if its really necessary.